# Replace with use of regular expression result

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say I've got some text with a couple tags like this:

```
[twitter:jpunt]
```

I want to replace those into something like this:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/jpunt">@Jpunt</a>
```

How could I do this in Ruby? I've been researching regular expressions for a couple of hours, just with a lot of frustration as a result. Anyone?

Comment: You don't need a regulare expression to replace a constant. Just search and replace.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
initial = "[twitter:jpunt]"
link = initial.gsub(/\[twitter:(\w+)\]/i, '<a href="http://twitter.com/\1">@\1</a>')
```

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with this answer. The only thing it doesn't do is capitalize the handle. Which I don't think it should, anyway. So +1 from me :)

Comment: Capitalizing the handle wasn't the point indeed. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is one line code (click [here](http://ideone.com/eI8ef) to test this code) >>

```
output = input.gsub(/\[([^:]+):([^\]]+)\]/) {
  '<a href="http://' + $1 + '.com/' + $2 + '">@' + $2.capitalize + '</a>' }
```

The above code works with any tag name. If you want just *twitter* to be allowed, then go with modification:

```
output = input.gsub(/\[twitter:([^\]]+)\]/) {
  '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + $1 + '">@' + $1.capitalize + '</a>' }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough example. Out of all things in tech, regexp is the thing I shutdown every time.